# Python 2.x: How to mock subprocess.Popen if stdin=PIPE

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-mock

I am trying to mock below function

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE    
def run_query():
    sql_cmd = "Some Query"
    process = Popen(["sqlplus", "-S", "/", "as", "sysdba"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    process.stdin.write(sql_cmd)
    (process_stdout, process_stderr) = process.communicate()
```

Below is the test function I wrote:

```
@patch('subprocess.Popen')
def test_run_query(Popen):
    Popen.return_value.communicate.return_value = (2, 1)
```

However, I am getting below error

```
Error occured while running sql command
Error output:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
F
```

I tried other stackoverflow post but this kind of example is not there. Any help please.

Comment: Your mock looks weird. The return values from `communicate` should be strings. Of course, without more knowledge of your test scenario, we can't know which strings you expect.

Comment: @tripleee consider any string that I will modify as per requirement. The main issue here is I am not able to write mock when STDIN = PIPE.

Comment: Note: writing to stdin is usually done at the time of calling `process.communicate`.

Comment: @win so can you please help here in writting the mock code. Got stuck here. Consider any output string that I will replace as per requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are patching `Popen` within the wrong namespace.

You need to patch the name `Popen` in the namespace where it is looked up, not where it is defined. Assuming `mypackage/mymodule.py` is the module in which `run_query` is defined:

```
from mypackage.mymodule import run_query

@patch('mypackage.mymodule.Popen')
def test_run_query(mock_popen):
    proc = mock_popen.return_value
    proc.communicate.return_value = "2", "1"
    out, err = run_query()
    assert out == "2"
    assert err == "1"
    proc.stdin.write.assert_called_once_with("Some Query")
```

See [*Where to patch*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) in the mock documentation for more info.

Comment: i am importing Pipe from subprocess in original module so I need to give same in test module. Following this , never faced issue.

Comment: you are correct wim, i need to use Popen in the namespace where it is looked up. Your code till proc.communicate.return_value worked for me. Since, I pasted partial code so that is enough. Thanks.

Comment: Many Many Thanks :)